# How can I get an iframe to change its own height on a cross domain set up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have a page which loads a page from another domain in an iframe. After something happens on the foreign domain, I want the iframe to shrink itself by 500px. How would one go about this?

Just to be clear:

```
Page A holds an iframe with page B in it
```

I want to

```
Have page B run a script which will resize the iframe it lives in so that there 
is more room on page A
```

Comment: Do you have access to page a?

Comment: I do but I would prefer to not need it

Comment: Can `page a` have a window.postMessage event listener? If not, then i'd have to go with not possible.

Comment: @KevinB Thats what i'd recommend to, but you'd have to have access to page a